# Surface integral of $2x+y+2z=16$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, surfaces

Here's the question:

Find the surface area of the part of the plane $2x+y+2z=16$ bounded by the surfaces $x=0$, $y=0$ and $x^2+y^2=64$.

So, I know I have to parameterize the surface $S:\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}(u,v)$ and I currently have it parameterized as $\mathbf{x}(u,v)=(\sqrt{32}\cos{u},\sqrt{32}\sin{u},v)$ because we're dealing with a circle of radius $8$ in the first quadrant (octants 1 and 5). If my parameterization is correct, then 
$$\left\lVert\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial\mathbf{x}}{\partial u}\right\rVert=64.$$

I'm still confused about the bounds though. Obviously, $0\le u\le\pi/2$ but what about $v$?

Help!

Thank you :)

Comment: The parametrization of the cylinder should be $$(8 \cos{u},8 \sin{u},v)$$

Comment: @jamesh625 With your parametrization the equality $2x+y+2z=64$ doesn't hold.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that that might be the problem... Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: @jamesh625 I would write $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$. Then you'll simply have the graph of a class $C^\infty$ function, which necessarily gives a parametrization. More exactly,
$$2x+y+2z=16\implies z=\dfrac{16-2x-y}{2}.$$
You can define $$f:U\to \Bbb R^2, x\mapsto \dfrac{16-2x-y}{2}$$ where $U=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2: x^2+y^2\leq 64 \land x\ge 0\land y\ge 0\}$ and 
$$\mathbf{x}(u,v)=(u,v,f(u,v))$$ with $(u,v)\in U$.

Comment: Okay so, so far I've got $\mathbf{x}(u,v)=(8\cos{u},8\sin{u},v)$ and $\left\lVert\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf{x}}{\partial v}\right\rVert=64$ and $I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{?}^{?}\frac{64}{2}(16-16\cos{u}-8\sin{u})dvdu$. My only real problem that remains is finding the bounds for $v$. Any ideas about how I should go about this? I tried using the intercepts of the plane with the axes and got $0\le v\le8$ but this was not correct. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The parametrization of $2x+y+2z=16$ bounded by the surfaces $x=0$, $y=0$ and $x^2+y^2=64$ can be naively parametrized by:
$$
S: \mathbf{\Phi}(x,y) = \left(x,y , \frac{16-2x-y}{2}\right),
$$
now we want to find the bounds on $x$ and $y$: for a point on $x^2+y^2=64$ with a fixed $x$-coordinate, $0\leq x\leq 8$: $y = \sqrt{64-x^2}$. Therefore for a point on this surface:
$$
0\leq x\leq 8,
\\
0\leq y \leq \sqrt{64-x^2}.
$$

Now the integral to compute the area is:
$$
A = \iint_S 1 \,dS = \int^8_0\int^{\sqrt{64-x^2}}_0 \left|\frac{\partial \mathbf{\Phi}}{\partial x}\times \frac{\partial \mathbf{\Phi}}{\partial y}\right| dydx = \int^8_0\int^{\sqrt{64-x^2}}_0\frac{3}{2}dydx = \frac{3}{2}\int^8_0 \sqrt{64-x^2}\,dx.
$$
This is like computing a slanted flat face's area from $\{x\geq 0,y\geq 0: x^2+y^2\leq 64\}$ (it is highly recommended you sketch the graph yourself).